# Editing heartbeat LED trigger

Tags: raspbian, kernel, led, driver

I am trying to edit the timer of heartbeat trigger on RPi Zero. I have found original .c file of kernel driver here https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.4.y/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-heartbeat.c. But when I look into my Pi's kernel drivers, in directory with triggers `/lib/modules/5.4.51+/kernel/drivers/leds/trigger` there are only three triggers and none of them are heartbeat : `ledtrig-camera.ko  ledtrig-netdev.ko  ledtrig-transient.ko`. So I am assuming the heartbeat trigger is defined elsewhere.

Where can I find and edit the heartbeat trigger of led ?

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69674/are-there-other-act-led-trigger-options-besides-mmc-and-heartbeat) - I don't think it's a complete answer to your Question, but it may provide useful clues. And if you find **the answer**, please post it here... I'm interested.

Comment: And this [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/fabio-d/block-led-trigger) may be relevant also. Never imagined this objective would be so complicated. And this is cool - [an LED heartbeat driver that resembles a ***real heart***](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-heartbeat.c.html).

Comment: I have tried writing my own module, but it is really hell to get it working on raspbian with their undocumented stuff. I am just updating that I will be continuing to work on it in 2 weeks, now I am taking a pause because of school stuff.

Comment: Take heart - if it were easy, anyone could do it :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to build a kernel object for `ledtrig-heartbeat.c`, you need to add [`CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_HEARTBEAT=Y`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.4.y/drivers/leds/trigger/Kconfig) to your kernel configuration:

```
 config LEDS_TRIGGER_HEARTBEAT
    tristate "LED Heartbeat Trigger"
    help
      This allows LEDs to be controlled by a CPU load average.
      The flash frequency is a hyperbolic function of the 1-minute
      load average.
If unsure, say Y.
```

Kernel configuration can usually be changed by running `make menuconfig` in the kernel source folder.

Comment: so in order to build the object I have to rebuild whole kernel ?

Comment: No, you can just jun `make modules_prepare; make M=drivers/leds/trigger modules; depmod`.