# What is the correct syntax for using GPIO input to trigger dtparam=act_led_trigger=gpio?

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

I have a GPS receiver connected to a Pi, with 1PPS input connected to GPIO4. This GPS module does not have a PPS or lock LED, so I would like to have it indicate with the activity LED. Based on the output of `cat /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/led0/trigger` I see that "gpio" is a trigger option, but I don't see how to declare *which* GPIO is used!

I have been looking through [ledtrig-gpio.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/c9226080e513181ffb3909a905e9c23b8a6e8f62/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-gpio.c) to figure out what syntax it wants but I haven't made any progress so far.

For what it's worth, I am using a Pi 3b+ with DietPi (Debian Buster).

Thanks!

Comment: Read through `/boot/overlays/README` and search for `act_led_gpio`

Comment: Hm, I don't think this is what I am looking for - act_led_gpio seems to be the GPIO pin that you redirect the "activity" behavior to a GPIO pin so you could use an external LED instead of the onboard one. What I want to do is have the activity LED reflect the state of a GPIO pin (e.g. GPIO high = LED lit).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood

Comment: No worries - I know what I'm asking is a little bit strange, but according to the documentation, it can be done!

Comment: *according to the documentation* - which documentation?

Comment: No official documentation that I have been able to find because this feature doesn't seem to be well understood. The output of `cat /sys/devices/platform/leds/leds/led0/trigger` lists all of the available triggers. They are also listed in this post here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69759/130291

Comment: the description for trigger=gpio is `Flash when a certain GPIO is high???` ... which "certain" GPIO? I see people setting trigger to gpio, then in code setting brightness to 0 or 1 to turn the LED off/on ... but you can achieve the same with trigger=none, so ... Since reading this question, I've realised I would also like to drive the LED from GPIO (without writing code to toggle it) - so, been searching too, and found nothing useful